# Trying to use "Kinect Region" in the Visual gesture builder code gives an error system.reflection.targetinvocationexception

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am trying to use the kinect region with the Visual gesture builder code.
I have added the correct references for VGB and Wpf controls. I am trying to infuse my application with the VGB code so that i can have these customized gestures perform some function in my application.

Please suggest me the way I can use the VGB with my application along with the hand cursor.I am also posting a picture for the inner exception.
[image]

```
public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            KinectRegion.SetKinectRegion(this, kinectRegion);

            var app = ((App)Application.Current);
            app.KinectRegion = kinectRegion;

            this.kinectRegion.KinectSensor = KinectSensor.GetDefault();

            var dataSource = DataSource.GetGroup("Group-1");
            this.itemsControl.ItemsSource = dataSource;

            // set IsAvailableChanged event notifier
            this.kinectSensor.IsAvailableChanged += this.Sensor_IsAvailableChanged;

            // open the sensor
            this.kinectSensor.Open();

            // set the status text
            this.StatusText = this.kinectSensor.IsAvailable ? Properties.Resources.RunningStatusText
                                                            : Properties.Resources.NoSensorStatusText;

            // open the reader for the body frames
            this.bodyFrameReader = this.kinectSensor.BodyFrameSource.OpenReader();

            // set the BodyFramedArrived event notifier
            this.bodyFrameReader.FrameArrived += this.Reader_BodyFrameArrived;

            // initialize the BodyViewer object for displaying tracked bodies in the UI


            // initialize the gesture detection objects for our gestures
            this.gestureDetectorList = new List<GestureDetector>();

            // initialize the MainWindow
            this.InitializeComponent();

            // set our data context objects for display in UI
            this.DataContext = this;


            // create a gesture detector for each body (6 bodies => 6 detectors) and create content controls to display results in the UI

            int maxBodies = this.kinectSensor.BodyFrameSource.BodyCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < maxBodies; ++i)
            {
                GestureResultView result = new GestureResultView(false, false, 0.0f);
                GestureDetector detector = new GestureDetector(this.kinectSensor, result);
                this.gestureDetectorList.Add(detector);                

                // split gesture results across the first two columns of the content grid
                ContentControl contentControl = new ContentControl();
                contentControl.Content = this.gestureDetectorList[i].GestureResultView;




            }
        }


And my Mainwindow.Xaml

<Window x:Class="Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.DiscreteGestureBasics.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.DiscreteGestureBasics"
          xmlns:controls="http://schemas.microsoft.com/kinect/2014"
        Title="Discrete Gesture Basics"
        Height="650" Width="750"
        Closing="MainWindow_Closing">

    <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl">
        <controls:KinectRegion x:Name="kinectRegion">

        </controls:KinectRegion>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```